# Can Express with EJS render HTML to a variable (so I can send as e-mail)?

Tags: email, node.js, view, express, ejs

I am writing a nodejs application that will be sending html e-mail using [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs).  Basically I provide the html to send as a variable that I attach to the message.

Rather than build this variable using lots of string concatenation, I'd like to just render a view using [express/ejs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and save the contents to the variable.

So instead of doing:

```
messageHtml = '<html>'+ ....
message.attach({data: messageHtml, alternative: true});
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
messageHtml = render('emailTemplate.ejs', viewArgs);
message.attach({data: messageHtml, alternative: true});
```

Can this be done, and if so, how?!

Comment: it's possible, but is different depending which view engine you're using with express.  What view engine have you set for express?  It would look something like: app.set('view engine', 'your engine here');

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just `require` ejs directly and use as per the [example](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/master/examples/list.js), e.g simplified usage (without caching):

```
var ejs = require('ejs')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , str = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/emailTemplate.ejs', 'utf8'); 

var messageHtml = ejs.render(str, viewArgs);

message.attach({data: messageHtml, alternative: true});
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you--so obvious in hindsight and very related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590333/how-can-i-turn-an-ejs-template-into-a-string I just didn't make the connection :-P

Comment: View helpers you've added to express won't work if you do it this way.

Comment: May be, but I don't think that was a requirement from the question.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch do you have a suggested solution so that view helpers work?